# Login form does not offer password saving on Chrome

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, reactjs

I'm having a login form created with React. It's using `window.fetch` (polyfill) for handling the request and `react-router` for proceeding to the correct page after login.

The problem is that Chrome is not offering the possibility for saving username+password while Firefox, Safari and IE does (probably Opera too).

I'm currently testing it against localhost with http only, but I don't think this is the issue.

Here's the code:

```
doSignIn: function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  this.context.SignInAction.signIn(evt.target.action, {
    email: this.credentials.email,
    password: this.credentials.password
  })
  .then(() => {
    this.transitionTo('/');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    this.setState({incorrectSignIn: true});
    React.findDOMNode(that.refs.email).focus();
  });
},
```

(rendering part):

```
<form autoComplete='on' method='POST' action='/site/sign-in' onSubmit={this.doSignIn}>
  <ul className='signIn'>
    <li className={classesNotification}>Invalid e-mail or password</li>
    <li>
      <input
        ref='email'
        type='email'
        defaultValue={this.credentials.email}
        placeholder='your e-mail address'
        required
        autoFocus='true' />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input
        type='password'
        defaultValue={this.credentials.password}
        placeholder='password'
        required /></li>
    <li><button type='submit'>Sign in</button></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

I looked for similar cases, but most of them was claiming it's caused by `autocomplete=off`. This is not the case in my situation.

I also checked the question: [Using reactjs and javascript - Chrome does not offer to remember passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997288/using-reactjs-and-javascript-chrome-does-not-offer-to-remember-passwords) , but it didn't help.

Is this a bug in Chrome or do I have to "circulate" my request somehow as a normal form post to get Chrome to understand we're actually sending username+password to the server?

**Note** that I've tried this with three different computers, one local, one from same network and one from virtual box, and also checked my own autocomplete preferences from Chrome. All is good from that point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but in case someone gets here with the same problem and the browser is saying the certificate is invalid then maybe the certificate needs to be trusted.

I had this problem of not being prompted to save my username/password for an internal company website. Then I realized that the browser was indicating the website certificate was invalid. Because this was an internal company website that I knew I could trust; I imported the certificate into Keychain Access, set trust to Allow Always and I was back in business!!

Chrome on Mac

Answer (score 0):

this issue was solved apparently when Chrome got updated (44.x).